# Scala : Class as a Parameter

Tags: scala

I want to pass a class as a parameter to my function in Scala.

e. g. `def getIndexes(...): Iterator` 
this is like the structure of function

I want to pass something like `Vertex.class` or say `Edge.class` as my parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are not after a type parameter to the method as per Gabriele's answer, but actually want to pass a Class object as a parameter, the type of the class object in Scala is parametric, so to accept any class you would do:

```
def myMethod(aClass: Class[_])
```

Answer (score 2):

Would passing a type parameter work for you?

```
def getIndexes[T]()
```